# Tool to create bootable FreeBSD USB flash drives

Tags: usb, bootable, unix

I am looking for a tool that can make a FreeBSD bootable USB flash drive.

Unfortunately [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) doesn't have this option.

I prefer a free sofware working in Windows, but Linux and paid solution can also be my 2nd option.

Comment: If UNetBootin does not what you need you might want to check out https://rufus.akeo.ie/

Comment: I suggest to add rufus as an answer, it can be useful for others.

Comment: Are you talking about a specific version of FreeBSD ?

Comment: I just like to install latest version, which is 10.2 at the moment

Comment: [netbootxyz](http://netboot.xyz/) might be a candidate. I've personally booted archLinux on it before.

Comment: In which format do you download FreeBSD? Is it ISO? Maybe [Win32DiskImager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/files/latest/download?source=navbar) works then

Comment: @ThomasWeller doesnt run in windows. it shows an error

Comment: Linux: `dd if=FreeBSD-12.0-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img of=/dev/your_device_name bs=1m conv=sync` :)

Answer (score 5):

Try [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/).

> UNetbootin allows you to create bootable Live USB drives for Ubuntu
>   and other Linux distributions without burning a CD.

It runs on Windows, Linux and  Mac OS X. It's licensed under the GNU General Public License (GPL) Version 2 or above, the source code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/unetbootin/unetbootin).

Here's a screenshot of the program taken from its website:

[image]

As you can see, **FreeBSD appears in the list of the available distributions**.

Comment: The main problem I have with this program is that it doesnt recognize my external hard disk (1 TB).I format the external hard disk to FAT32 with Gparted but still it doesnt recognize it. I tried the same procedure in windows with different programs without any success. Now I am searching to find a solution for it.

Comment: Are you searching a solution for a flash drive or a hard disk ? Your title states the first, your comment the latter.

Comment: I want to install it on my hard disk using 1 TB external hard disk

Comment: Unetbootin seems like such a fake program and never worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to give [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) a try.

It is reported to support FreeBSD and it has (like UnetBootIn) an option which not only lists USB sticks but external hard disks too:

[image: Rufus with advanced options]

Comment: Do you know which one is the currect version to use? ISO or memstick(dd)

Comment: If I use [memstick version](ftp://ftp4.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/amd64/ISO-IMAGES/10.2/FreeBSD-10.2-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img),it it created bootable stick. after booting with stick, my pc tries to lard Freebds installer but I receive and error: `can't load kernel`

Comment: If I use iso version, I receive [an error](http://s16.postimg.org/uksulch11/Capture1.png) :  `This image is either non-bootable, or it uses a boot or compression method that is not supported by Rufus...`

Comment: I used the i386 memdisk and transferred it to stick with dd method. Then I was able to boot beyond kernel but it failed later on with a different error message. I assume that rufus does not fully support FreeBSD.

Answer (score 3):

I was in the same situation some time ago and found only 2 solutions, one for Windows one for Linux (Etcher supports 3 major platforms though, I tried only on Linux):

Rufus and Etcher

### Etcher

> Flash OS images to SD cards & USB drives, safely and easily.
>
> Etcher is a powerful OS image flasher built with web technologies to
> ensure flashing an SDCard or USB drive is a pleasant and safe
> experience. It protects you from accidentally writing to your
> hard-drives, ensures every byte of data was written correctly and much
> more.

Source: [Etcher Github repository](https://github.com/resin-io/etcher)

Etcher homepage: [Homepage of Etcher bootable USB creator](https://etcher.io/)

[image: Etcher screenshot with animated gif]

---

### Rufus

From [Rufus homepage](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)

> Rufus is a utility that helps format and create bootable USB flash
> drives, such as USB keys/pendrives, memory sticks, etc.
>
> It can be especially useful for cases where:
>
> - you need to create USB installation media from bootable ISOs
>   (Windows, Linux, UEFI, etc.)
> - you need to work on a system that doesn't have an OS installed
> - you need to flash a BIOS or other firmware from DOS
> - you want to
>   run a low-level utility

[image: Rufus bootable USB creator screenshot]

---

I like Etcher very much maybe because it was hard for me to find something which does the job in Linux, maybe because of its nice interface. Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** Unetbootin and the others have never worked for me.

**EDIT 2:** I just saw you're trying to install from external hdd. Then you might try LILI or Universal USB Installer, as mentioned at [this page](https://www.linux.com/answers/there-way-i-can-install-linux-my-external-hard-drive-so-i-can-boot-it).